# Android register error AsyncTask

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an error in doInBackground() when I try to register a new user in my application and I don't understand why.
I give you my register.php code and my SignUp.java class.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');

// Recup elem to make the sign_up connection
$name=$_POST["name"];
$firstName=$_POST["firstName"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$mail=$_POST["mail"];
$nationality=$_POST["nationality"];
$city=$_POST["city"];

//create array
$response = array();

if (!empty($_POST)) {
if (empty($_POST['name']) ||empty($_POST['firstName']) ||   empty($_POST['mail']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['nationality']) || empty($_POST['city'])) {
// Create some data that will be the JSON response 
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty .";

      //die is used to kill the page, will not let the code below to be executed. It will also
      //display the parameter, that is the json data which our android application will parse to be //shown to the users
      die(json_encode($response));
  }

 //prepare the insert statement
 $query = $handler->prepare ('INSERT  INTO login (name, firstName, mail, password, nationality, city) VALUES ( :name, :firstName, :mail, :password, :country, :city) ') ;

//bind the parameters
$query->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':firstName', $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':mail', $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':country', $nationality, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//execute the prepared statement
$query->execute();

 $row = $query->fetchColumn();
 if (!empty($row)) {
   $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["message"] = "You have been sucessfully register";

   die(json_encode($response));
}
else{

$response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "invalid register ";
die(json_encode($response));
}



 }
 else{

 $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = " One or both of the fields are empty ";
 die(json_encode($response));
 }

 ?>
```

My SignUp.java

```
 public class SignUpActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 // Edit and Button that the user fill
 private EditText eName, eFirstName, eMail, ePass, eNationality, eCity ;
 private Button bRegister;

 // Progress Dialog
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;


 //JSON parser class
 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://10.0.0.35/BD_Projet/register.php";
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);      
    eName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    eFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName); 
    eMail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    ePass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
    eNationality = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nationality);
    eCity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.city);
    bRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.inscription);
    bRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
          }
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.inscription:
                new AttempSignUp().execute();
    // here we have used, switch case, because on login activity you may    //also want to show registration button, so if the user is new ! we can go the //registration activity , other than this we could also do this without switch //case.
    default:
          break;
    }
  }

 class AttempSignUp extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
     /**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 * */
    boolean failure = false;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for add new user...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           // here Check for success tag
    int success;
    String name = eName.getText().toString();
    String firstName = eFirstName.getText().toString();
    String email = eMail.getText().toString();
    String password = ePass.getText().toString();
    String nationality = eNationality.getText().toString();
    String city = eCity.getText().toString();
    try {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", firstName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nationality", nationality));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(REGISTER_URL, "POST", params);

        // checking  log for json response
        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

        // success tag for json
        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
          Log.d("Successfully Register!", json.toString());

          Intent i = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,ConnectedActivity.class);
          finish();
// this finish() method is used to tell android os that we are done with current //activity now! Moving to other activity
                startActivity(i);
          return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }else{

          return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
    }
    /**
 * Once the background process is done we need to  Dismiss the progress dialog asap
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {

    pDialog.dismiss();
    if (message != null){
          Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
} 

}
```

And config.php

```
 <?php
 try{
      $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=projet', 'root', 'xxxx');
      $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    }catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
 ?>
```

And it's my error in the Logcat :

```
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072): Process: com.mickKoza.tournamentmanagement, PID: 6072
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at com.mickKoza.tournamentmanagement.SignUpActivity$AttempSignUp.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:104)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at com.mickKoza.tournamentmanagement.SignUpActivity$AttempSignUp.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:1)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-14 17:10:39.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6072):     ... 4 more
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mickKoza.tournamentmanagement.SignUpActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{24b51ea V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at com.mickKoza.tournamentmanagement.SignUpActivity$AttempSignUp.onPreExecute(SignUpActivity.java:75)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at com.mickKoza.tournamentmanagement.SignUpActivity.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:55)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-14 17:10:40.025: E/WindowManager(6072):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is that your complete logcat output? Also, you should start the other activity in `onPostExecute()`, otherwise you are probably going to have another exception when showing your `Toast`.

Comment: My error when I try to debug is in this method in the class ThreadGroup.java:                                                                                                                                                                                     public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.uncaughtException(t, e);

Comment: You need to do what I suggested in my first comment. Send your response to `onPostExecute()` and start the `Activity` there.

Comment: No, I mean send a response to `onPostExecute()` and from there decide to show the Toast, start an activity, or whatever.